# can't understand some Go code

Tags: go

While I was reading the code of package "net", I found some code like this:

```
// first returns the first address which satisfies strategy, or if
// none do, then the first address of any kind.
func (addrs addrList) first(strategy func(Addr) bool) Addr {
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        if strategy(addr) {
            return addr
        }
    }
    return addrs[0]
}
```

I am really confused about why the func first includes another func named func(Addr), and how does this code implement the behaviour which the comments say?

Comment: func(Addr) bool is the **type** of the parameter _strategy_. So the argument "strategy" must be a function that takes  something of type _Addr_ and returns true or false.

Comment: so , one thing i want to make sure is that : func(Addr) bool is a type like "string" or "int"?  but how does this func return the fist address which satisfies strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1 func (addrs addrList) first(strategy func(Addr) bool) Addr {
2    for _, addr := range addrs {
3        if strategy(addr) {
4            return addr
         }
     }
5    return addrs[0]
  }
```

In words:

1. function on `addrs` named `first` returns `Addr` takes `strategy` argument which must be a function that takes `Addr` and return `bool`.
2. `for` each `addr` in `range` of `addrs` apply function `strategy` on `addr`
3. if it (the `strategy` func) returns `true`
4. then whole function `first` returns that `addr`
5. whole function `first` return the very first `[0]` `Addr` from `addrs`, implied: which only happens if none of `strategy` calls on `addr` in `range` of `addrs` returned `true`.

Answer (score 1):

consider strategy as a filter function, it just checks if addr in the range loop can pass the filter or not
another and completely equal way to do this is like

```
func strategy(addr Addr) bool {
    if addr == ... {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func main(){
    addr := first(strategy)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Func `first` accepts as an argument `strategy` another function with type `func(Addr) bool`. 
So second function should take an `Addr` as input and return `bool` whether adder is ok.

As first such `Addr` found first function exits and returns it.

Logins is similar to filters - iterate a list until first matching value is found.

And as a last resort if for no one `Addr` value was got positive reply first function returns a first value in slice.